# How remove an item from the Typeahead React multiselect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead

In the `TokenSkill` component, it adds`onRemove = {props.onRemove}`. However, with an element in multiselect, there is no cross to delete the selected element.

Demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/74n5rvr75x

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Token, tokenContainer, Typeahead } from "react-bootstrap-typeahead";

const styles = {
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  textAlign: "center"
};

const TokenSkill = tokenContainer(props => {
  return (
    <div
      {...props}
      onClick={event => {
        event.stopPropagation();
        props.onClickCustom(event);
      }}
      onRemove={props.onRemove}
      className="tokenSkill"
      tabIndex={0}>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
});

class App extends React.Component {
  render = () => {
    const options = [
      { id: "house", name: "House" },
      { id: "house2", name: "House2" },
      { id: "house3", name: "House3" }
    ];

    return (
      <Typeahead
        clearButton
        labelKey="name"
        multiple
        allowNew
        onChange={console.log("toot!")}
        options={options}
        placeholder="Choose a state..."
        renderToken={(...args) => this.getSkillEffectToken(...args)}
      />
    );
  };

  getSkillEffectToken = (option, onRemove, index) => {
    return (
      <TokenSkill
        onRemove
        key={index}
        onClickCustom={event => {
          alert("bad! The window still shows");
        }}
      >
        {`${option.name}`}
      </TokenSkill>
    );
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code updated and refer this working clone of your source - https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-cherry-7kpui

It seems you have some CSS issue on alignment for global clear all data(X), adding to that you are not passing data properly for the tabIndex and onClick data to TokenSkill method, your code is updated please validate and provide feedback

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Token, tokenContainer, Typeahead } from "react-bootstrap-typeahead";

const styles = {
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  textAlign: "center"
};

const TokenSkill = tokenContainer(props => {
  console.log("2", props);
  return (
    <div
      {...props}
      onClick={event => {
        event.stopPropagation();
        props.onClickCustom(event);
      }}
      tabIndex={props.key}
      className={"tokenSkill"}
    >
      {props.children}
      <button aria-label="Clear" class="close rbt-close" type="button">
        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Clear</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
});

class App extends React.Component {
  render = () => {
    const options = [
      { id: "house", name: "House" },
      { id: "house2", name: "House2" },
      { id: "house3", name: "House3" }
    ];

    return (
      <Typeahead
        clearButton
        labelKey="name"
        multiple
        onChange={console.log("toot!")}
        options={options}
        placeholder="Choose a state..."
        renderToken={(...args) => this.getSkillEffectToken(...args)}
      />
    );
  };

  getSkillEffectToken = (option, onRemove, index) => {
    console.log(onRemove);
    return (
      <TokenSkill
        key={index}
        onClickCustom={evt => {
          onRemove(evt);
          // alert("bad! The window still shows");
        }}
      >
        {`${option.name}`}
      </TokenSkill>
    );
  };
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: In this line: `onClickCustom={evt => {
          onRemove(evt);
        }}` I have error: `onRemove is not a function`

Comment: Can you check which version you are using? For typeahead? If yo receive onRemove s not function yo need to refer like props.onRemove() - check // v2.0
<Typeahead
  ...
  multiple
  renderToken={(option, onRemove, index) => {
    // Your own token rendering code.
  }}
/>

// v3.0
<Typeahead
  ...
  multiple
  renderToken={(option, props, index) => {
    // Your own token rendering code.
    // `onRemove` is now `props.onRemove`
  }}
/>

Comment: source - https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/blob/master/docs/Upgrading.md

Comment: Can you let me know the status of this? Let me know if yo need help?

Comment: I have version  "react-bootstrap-typeahead": "^3.4.6". I changed to:  `getSkillEffectToken = (option, props, index) => {`; `<TokenSkill
            key={index}
            onClickCustom={event => {
              props.onRemove(event);  
            }}` but I have the same problem

Comment: in your example:   https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-cherry-7kpui when I click in token , token is delete;  Is it possible to set it to remove the token only when I click only the cross?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198764/discussion-between-kannan-g-and-umbro).